# Removing file from .gitignore in webstorm

Tags: gitignore, webstorm

I was searching the web for hour now...
I can't seem to find where the gitignore file is located,and it's ruining my life. I have to remove one file from there. I'm using WebStorm 8
Any help?

Comment: If a .gitignore file exists it will be in the root of the repository folder. Since the filename starts with a "." it counts as a hidden file.  Make sure you have the correct options set so that you can view hidden files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` can be in any folder inside your git repository. And the patterns in `.gitignore` of child folder will overwrite the ones in parent folder.

It may be hidden when you use `ls` in your `Git Bash`. Just use `ls -a`.

From the [doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the
>   path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level
>   files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those
>   in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These
>   patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file.